# Error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.kie.kogito:kogito-legacy-api:jar is missing

Tags: quarkus

Due to the vulnerabilities within the quarkus version of 2.7.5.Final we tried to upgrade to the version 2.16.10.Final but we are facing the issue as below error:

`build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.kie.kogito:kogito-legacy-api:jar is missing.`

However it was working fine for 2.7.5.Final quarkus version, can you please suggest for which quarkus version to be used to fix vulnerabilities against using Kogito legacy api?

We have tried upgrading the quarkus version as there were vulnerabilities found with version 2.7.5.Final to tried to upgrade with 2.16.10.Final but one of the quarkus associated dependency is missed. However tried several other versions but still we are not able to resolve this issue.
`build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.kie.kogito:kogito-legacy-api:jar is missing.`